# I need an AJAX cart like these below:

Tags: 7

Is there a project or something that already integrated a cart similar to:

http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/cart.html

or an integration of jcart:

http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/

I tried ubercart but despite the fact is an overkill it doesn't work like these.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't write the required version. I found a module [Ecwid shopping cart](http://drupal.org/project/ecwid_shopping_cart). This module has drag and drop features for items and ajax support everywhere.

For more information, have a look at [Ecwid Demo](http://www.ecwid.com/demo-frontend.html).